# Entity Validation failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am trying to update my SQL Server db with a background service. the data are taken from an 3rd api and I have also created the table and the entity. however I an exception of VALIDATION FAILURE when i run my program.
This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trivia] (
[QID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Category]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Type]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Difficulty]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Question]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Correct_answer]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[incorrect_answer] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Trivia] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QID] ASC)
```

);

this is the class which my methods is call from Global.asax

```
    {

    private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public static void schedulePhase()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetQuestion);
        timer.Interval = 30000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

        public static async void GetQuestion(object x, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1");
                var question = new Trivia();
                question = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Trivia>(response);

                if (question != null)
                {
                    MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities();

                    
                    dc.Trivias.Add(question);
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                }
```

and this is my table model

```
    public partial class Trivia
{
    public int QID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Correct_answer { get; set; }
    public string incorrect_answer { get; set; }
}
```

}
now I get thrown this when i run my app.

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The Category field is required.; The Type field is required.; The Difficulty field is required.; The Question field is required.; The Correct_answer field is required.; The incorrect_answer field is required.'

have I missed something here?

Comment: The code looks like MS SQL aka SQL Server one, not MySQL. DBMS tag replaced.

Comment: There are several issues with this code. HttpClient is getting disposed even though it shouldn't. The DbContext is *not* disposed, even though it should. `async void GetQuestion` is a bug - `async void` is only meant for event handlers and such methods can't be awaited, which means the application won't wait for this method to complete. The operation can easily get cancelled before it even starts. You should use `async Task` for asynchronous method that don't return data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had it as a async Task but then it throws me exception here 'code'
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetQuestion); at timer class. exception says that method doesnt have a return value.

Comment: Event handlers are the only place where `async void` is used. The naming convention though is to use a name similar to the event like `OnElapsed`, `OnElapsedAsync` or `Elapsed_Handler`, not `GetQuestion`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response from that web API, the string returned is a JSON encoded envelope with fields `response_code` and `results`, the latter of which is a list of objects that can be deserialised into the `Trivia` class you have created.

You would therefore need to extract the `response`'s `results[0]` into the JSON decoder, not the whole response string.

Comment: so u are saying I should `foreach(trivia x in question)` {dc.trivias.add(question)?

Answer (score 0):

All fields of your table are required.

```
            //Here you instantiate your question object
            var question = new Trivia();
            question = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Trivia>(response);


            //So, here it won't be null. 
            if (question != null)
            {
                MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities();

                //Here, if any property of the question object is null, you will have the validation error.
                dc.Trivias.Add(question);
                dc.SaveChanges();

            }
```

For me, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response); returns empty.
So, as you send NULL for NOT NULL database fields, you have this error.

I think you should check what it returns your deserialisation.

Comment: yes you are right it does return null...I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here [.NET Deserialize JSON from GET API with header from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914812/net-deserialize-json-from-get-api-with-header-from-c-sharp)